# How to prevent hyphenation at _

Tags: hyphenation

It know that I can prevent hyphenation of a whole word with `\nohyphens`, but how to avoid hyphenation at a character like `_` (`\_` in the source). `\nohyphens` doesn't even seem to work for `_\`.

I'm looking for any solution, i.e. one which excludes the character for hyphenation for the whole document or a command which I can apply on every occurance of `\_` - the first approach is preferred.

Comment: by default you wpn't get hyphenation at `\_` so you should (as always) give an example document showing the problem, but in general in classic tex or xetex you can prevent hyphenation at a character `x` by giving `x` a non zero lower case code (that prevents it being considered part of a word, so changes all the hyphenation not just at that letter

Comment: It would be nice to have an example to see the real problem and give the proper solution, but  I guess that  `\mbox{xxxx\_xxxx}` should work.

Comment: @Fran `\mbox{xxxx\_xxxx}` works, thank you. I realialize that the question isn't good, I'll improve it as soon as I find the time. If you post an answer (somehow working around the missing explanation in the question), I'll accept it.